# Assimilating gcd and linear combinations

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have understood proof-wise the reason why linear combinations form the invariant property of gcd, i.e. at each step the gcd will be the same (a positive value) irrespective of the reduced new value being dividend & divisor at each successive step.

Algebraically speaking, it is stated as :

Given integers $b$ (dividend) and $c$ (divisor) $ > 0$, we make a repeated application of the division algorithm, to obtain a series of equations :

$b = cq_1 + r_1,   0<r_1<c$, ---//$r_1$ is remainder, $q_1$ is quotient

$c = r_1q_2 + r_2  , 0<r_2<r_1,$ ---//old divisor ($c$) is new quotient, $r_1$ is new quotient

...

$r_{j-2} = r_{j-1}q_j + r_j , 0<r_j<r_{j-1}$

But, when I see a proof like :

Two integers $a,b$ are coprime iff there exist integers $x$ and $y$ such that: $ax + by =1$.

Proof: As gcd is the smallest positive linear combination, and if any other linear combination, let c,  is $1 \exists x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$; then as gcd$\mid c, \forall c$, so gcd must be also $1$.

Then I think if it is really so difficult to get a particular value as $1$, that can prove co-prime for those two (or more) numbers. I cannot fathom the deepness of virtually any linear combination of not co prime integers, not being able to generate $1$ as a linear combination. I mean that one cannot get any intuition or logic into this, and may feel that getting any possible value as linear combination must be an issue of choosing suitable value as multiplier for both (or more, if more numbers are considered) the numbers concerned.

*Addendum* It is off-topic, but if could get help to format the horizontal spacing in the series of equations for gcd.

Comment: I agree, but a sense of it, that can show the impossibility of non co-prime integers being able to generate $1$ as a linear combination, is not coming by such 'dry' proofs. I could not use a better word than 'dry', but do not know of how to better express the lack of image / intuition that such proof brings.

Comment: Well here is a better representation, consider graph of $2x+4y=1$, can you find any lattice points on this line?

Comment: @homing3951 Of course not. One cannot get any lattice(integer) value, even if one coordinate is absent. But, how does it concern with not co-prime integers being unable to generate $1$ as gcd.

Comment: So no linear integral combination can give 1 for 2 and 4, similar for other such pairs.

Comment: @homing3951 So, you mean to say that if $a=2$ and $b=4$ for a linear combination of divisor as $a$ and dividend as $b$ (and their respective linear multipliers as $x$ and $y$); then impossible to generate 1 as a linear combination, for any possible value of $x$ and $y$. If so, then this reasoning must be specified in some text, or reference somewhere. How, can I find such resource, please provide reference for further details / exercises on that.

Comment: you wont get any lattice point on 6x+4y=1 as well and so for all non co-prime pairs.